# how to invoke addeventlistener from a hta file when user clicks on internet menu item

Tags: javascript

When i call this below script in a normal html it is working fine but when i call this script from IE extension(clicks on IE menu item) canvas is created sucessfully but the ***canvas.addeventlistener*** is not working.How to invoke this event listener for IE extensions.

Please help me out as it has taken lot of my time

Below code in bold color is not working.

```
    OnToolbarButtonClick();

    function OnToolbarButtonClick() {

        var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
        var doc = parentwin.document;

        var width = Math.max(doc.documentElement.scrollWidth, parentwin.innerWidth);
        var height = Math.max(doc.documentElement.scrollHeight, parentwin.innerHeight);

        var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
        doc.body.appendChild(canvas);

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        canvas.style.top = '0';
        canvas.style.left = '0';
        canvas.style.zIndex = '99995';
        canvas.style.opacity = '0.7';

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(141, 161, 191)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
            alert('8');
        }, false);
    }
```